# How to create persistent livebroadcast?

Tags: youtube, stream, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I develop the mobile app with livestream feature and I need to get default livebroadcast with default livestream data.

When user didn't enable livestreams in his youtube account I show him message with link to https://www.youtube.com/live_streaming_signup .

After if user enabled livestreams in his youtube account I can't get default livebroadcast with broadcast type persistent.

My request url is: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=contentDetails&mine=true&broadcastType=persistent&access_token=

My response is:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#liveBroadcastListResponse",
 "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/5WQLBG6RLCbLPgwsAs3o13sBM98\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#liveBroadcast",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8\""
  }
 ]
}
```

Only after go to live dashboard page stream now I can got default livebroadcast with broadcast type persistent and then got livestream by default livebroadcast boundStremId

Why? How I can get default livebroadcast and default livestream without go to livestream dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your query, and just like you, I can get 200 response, but I can only get 1 result. So the alternative way that I used to get the live broadcast is by using the [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) under the DATA API. Here, you can use the `eventType=live` to get the live broadcast video.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

For the persistent broadcast, try to check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144186/how-to-get-stream-name-key-of-youtube-live-stream-now-service) if it can help you.

For more information check these related SO questions:

- [YouTube API live broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343459/youtube-api-live-broadcast)
- [How to get list of live video broadcasts using youtube api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786913/how-to-get-list-of-live-video-broadcasts-using-youtube-api-v3)